# Fastest way to access large array

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is it quicker to copy an element in a large array to another object or use the reference? When using the reference to the item in the large array, does it have to traverse the array to get to it?

```
var obj = HugeArray[54650];
var calc = obj.x * 2.43 + obj.y * 5.43 + obj.z * 4.323;
```

OR

```
var obj = $.extend(true, {}, HugeArray[54650]);
var calc = obj.x * 2.43 + obj.y * 5.43 + obj.z * 4.323;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> obj = HugeArray[54650];
> ```

Is *not* a reference to the item "in the array", but from now on `obj` is a direct reference to the object.

There no reason to make a copy of the item with `$.extend`, that only makes yours script slower.

Answer (score 3):

In *JavaScript*, an *Array* is a type of *Object*. Therefore, looking up `arr[x]` is the same as looking up `obj[x]` and because most *JavaScript* engines use hash tables, this is very fast and doesn't decrease dramatically even as more keys are added.

[Perf for properties vs variables **here**](http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-var).

Answer (score 0):

When you use a key, you are actually accessing a pointer. The pointer points (heyy) to the location of the value (in the memory). This is the fastest way to access data from an array. A loop is alway slower.

Im not familiar with the `$.extend` mehod though